# How can I create a base iOS Swift App "Template" in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an app written in Swift that I want to reuse multiple times but with minor customizations for each.

Rather than start from scratch or duplicate the project and rename it, is there a way to create a type of project template that I can then customize?

To add to the complexity, I am using Firebase and Pods as part of the project...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks. I was using the term "template" in the generic sense and not in the specific sense of how xcode supports templates. Not to exclude the xcode template as an option, my question is to solicit a variety of options as I believe many people face the issue and have come up with their preferred approach. As such, I do not agree that it is quite the same question. I'm happy to alter the wording if you have a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to create a type of project template

No. This was possible once, but it was very complex and the feature no longer exists.  You just have to save off a pristine copy of your project folder and start every new project by duplicating it. After all, that is basically what a template is, an example project to be copied.

Comment: Thank you. This is the approach I'll use (continue to use) as it seems much easier than going through the xcode template process for each such project. I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some other method.